# crear array multidimensional

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Necesito crear un array multidimensional para poder generar una grafia necesito que el array tenga el siguiente formato

```
data = [
    'name' => 'METROPOLITANO'
    'data' => [
        30,50,80,22,78
    ],
    'name' => 'VARGAS'
    'data' => [
        21,83,78,21,99,
    ]
]
```

estoy trabajando de esta forma pero no se como crear el arreglo de data

```
$grafica = DB::table('ordens')
                        ->select('nombre_cede','amount','mes')
                        ->where('nombre_cede','ACUEDUCTO METROPOLITANO')
                        ->get();
        $data;

        foreach($grafica as $i => $graf){
            // dd($graf);
            $data['name'] = $graf->nombre_cede;
            $data['data'] = [$graf->amount];

        }
```

estoy trabajando con el framework laravel 8 y postgresql.

la variable grafica tiene esta informacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En cada iteración estás pisando el valor de data

Comment: claro, lo que me gustaría saber es como manejar los datos a modo de evitar que no se sobrescriba el valor si no que cree un nuevo indice

Comment: Muestranos que tienes en $grafica antes de hacer el foreach

Comment: editada la pregunta y agregada la información que contiene la variable $grafica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La estructura inicial que muestras está mal, tiene los elementos de cada sub arreglo al mismo nivel. Debieran estar entre corchetes .

Si definimos que data elemento del resultado final debe tener la forma

```
$elemento = [
   'name' => 'string'
   'data' => [1, 2, 3]
];
```

Y que el conjunto debe tener la forma

```
$data = [
  $elemento1,
  $elemento2,
  $elemento3,
]
```

Entonces, en vez de:

```
data = [
    'name' => 'METROPOLITANO'
    'data' => [
        30,50,80,22,78
    ],
    'name' => 'VARGAS'
    'data' => [
        21,83,78,21,99,
    ]
]
```

Debiera ser

```
$data = [
    [
      'name' => 'METROPOLITANO'
      'data' => [
          30,50,80,22,78
      ],
    ], [
      'name' => 'VARGAS'
      'data' => [
          21,83,78,21,99,
      ]
   ]
]
```

Para mapear el resultado de la consulta a tu estructura, ten en cuenta que `$grafica` es una instancia de `Collection` (en realidad es una subclase de Collection, pero eso es irrelevante), por lo que te sería más fácil aprovechar su método `map`

```
$data = $grafica->map(
     fn($graf)=> [
      'name'=> $graf->nombre_cede, 
      'data' => [$graf->amount ]
     ]);
```

Que es una versión corta de

```
$data = $grafica->map(function($graf) {
    return [
      'name'=> $graf->nombre_cede, 
      'data' => [$graf->amount ]
     ];
});
```

#### Edit, me faltó algo

Mi colega [porloscerros-Ψ](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/92278/porloscerros-%CE%A8) me indicó en los comentarios algo en lo que no había reparado, y es que en los datos de muestra del OP hay `nombre_cede` repetidos, lo cual sumado a la estructura planteada originalmente me hizo caer en la cuenta que la solución requiere agregar el valor de `amount` para la misma `cede`. En todo caso la palabra, si se refiere a "jurisdicción" es `sede`. Yo en eso no cedo ni sedo.

Si la data en la tabla es

| nombre_cede | amount | mes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acueducto Metropolitano | 100 | Oct |
| Acueducto Metropolitano | 600 | Jun |
| Plaza de Armas | 400 | Eve |
| Plaza de Armas | 900 | Mar |
| Acueducto Metropolitano | 300 | Sep |

Mi solución daría tantos items en el array final como registros hay en la tabla, cada una con un array de un solo item en `data`

Para obtener en cambio un solo item por cada cede, y en éstos tantos items en la propiedad `data` como registros haya en la BBDD, yo lo haría con un reduce

```
$grafica->reduce(function($accum, $item) {
   $nombre_cede = $item['nombre_cede'];
   $cede = $accum->get($nombre_cede,['data'=>[]]);
   $cede['name'] = $nombre_cede;
   $cede['data'][] = $item['amount'];
   $accum->put($nombre_cede,$cede);
   return $accum;
},collect([]));
```

Esto es: inicializamos el reduce con una colección vacía. En cada iteración del bucle, extraemos el item correspondiente al nombre de la cede desde esa colección. Si no existe, obtenemos por defecto un array con la forma

```
 ['data' => []]
```

De manera que siempre podemos añadirle datos haciendo

```
 $cede['data'][] = $item['amount']
```

Al terminar ese bucle tenemos una colección cuyo contenido es

```
[
 'ACUEDUCTO METROPOLITANO' => [
                  'nombre_cede'=> 'ACUEDUCTO METROPOLITANO'
                  'amount' => [100, 600, 300]
                             ],
 'PLAZA DE ARMAS' => [
                  'nombre_cede'=> 'PLAZA DE ARMAS'
                  'amount' => [400, 900]
                             ],

]
```

Y aprovechando los métodos de conveniencia de las colecciones, el resultado requerido por el OP se obtiene con

```
 $data = $grafica->values()->toArray();
```

Ahora, por qué no usé un group by aguas arriba, en la consulta de la BBDD? La verdad, no es cosa de hacer un `GROUP BY` para convertir un campo numérico en un array que Laravel pueda entender nativamente. Habría que convertirlo a JSON y no sé si los métodos de agrupación de Eloquent query builder tienen cubierto ese caso de uso. Habría que usar una sentencia nativa de Database Query Builder, que es más rudo.

Y llegados a ese punto, las funciones para crear un array JSON no son exactamente iguales entre motores de bases de datos, así que la solución no es portátil. En postgres usarías `json_agg`, en mysql `JSON_ARRAYAGG` y en SQLite `json_group_array`. Eso significa que si un día quieres encapsular la consulta en una vista tendrás que  comprobar el driver de BBDD antes de correrlas. Por ejemplo, si quieres correr los tests en SQLite.

Comment: Coincido con la estructura esperada que propones para el array resultante, y también con usar los métodos de las colecciones para armar esa estructura (en vez de un foreach). Ahora, con la manera de armarlo que propones no bastaría para agrupar los valores de la propiedad `amount` en un mismo array anidado bajo la clave `data`, eso pondría sólo el valor de 1 `amount` en ese subarray, en vez de ir agregandole elementos .

Comment: Se me ocurre algo así `->groupBy("nombre_cede")->map(function ($group, $key) { return [ "name" => $key, "data" => $group->pluck("amount"), ]; }) ->values();` para lograr esa estructura, pero con todos los métodos disponibles para las colecciones, probablemente hay varias maneras de hacerlo.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ excelente acotación. Se me había pasado por alto que los registros de la BBDD repiten el nombre de la sede